# Receive an object from the net and distinguish it

Tags: java

I receive an object from the net through the the `getInputStream()` using `ObjectInputStream`
My question is:  once it's arrived from the net how can I distinguish it?Can i use `instance of`?

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream();

Object obj = ois.readObject();

if(obj instanceof ObjectA)
    ...
else  
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's not the ObjectInputStream that will be tested to know the class of the object you received.
You should use :

```
Object o = ois.readObject();
```

Then you can you instanceof or you can use `o.getClass().getName()`. Then you'll know what type of object it is.